# Microsoft Bing Custom Search returning strange reponse?

Tags: azure, search, bing, azure-cognitive-services

We previously used Bing Custom Search with the version 5.0 API. That has just stopped working over the last couple of weeks. Through the API EndPoint at https://www.customsearch.ai, any test just returns:

```
{
  "_type": "SearchResponse",
  "instrumentation": {
    "pingUrlBase": "https://www.bingapis.com/api/ping?IG=19E4BA520EAB45A191FD4CBEE7C72856&CID=151C188292876475082A13A293216596&ID=",
    "pageLoadPingUrl": "https://www.bingapis.com/api/ping/pageload?IG=19E4BA520EAB45A191FD4CBEE7C72856&CID=151C188292876475082A13A293216596&Type=Event.CPT&DATA=0"
  },
  "queryContext": {
    "originalQuery": "microsoft"
  },
  "rankingResponse": {}
}
```

I noticed a note saying Bing Custom Search has now moved over to Azure, so I've added that feature (Cognitive Services, API type:
Bing Custom Search API) to our Azure platform. It has been deployed and I got 2 new API keys. Using either of these, and the 7.0 API, still returns the same as above.

What's going on? The API Endpoint should work, but the response including rankingResponse is odd as that's not a documented response for custom search.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you will have to create your search instance again. You can go to customsearch.ai and create instance. It should give you "customconfig" Id on the "API endpoint" tab.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. Created a new instance on customsearch.ai, went to the API Endpoint tab, entered the key from my Azure Cognitive Services subscription and I get exactly the same output.

Is there a Microsoft support e-mail address for this, anyone??

Comment: I presume you have already added domains/subsites/webpages to which you want to restrict your search in your instance on customsearch.ai. Also, keys are meant for custom search and not for web search. I think you can post the issue here: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/598147-bing-custom-search.